# Should StackOverflow question quality standards also apply for politics questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

When hovering the upvote button, it says that "This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear". On StackOverflow this usually means [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, at least one attempt to solve the problem is highly recommended.

Of course, Politics is way less technical (or at least it looks that way). However, I see that there are questions that try to provide relevant context and references (e.g. [this one](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/18620/why-are-so-many-americans-against-obamacare)) and others providing a minimum context with no references (e.g. [this one](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/15933/why-is-president-trump-making-such-a-big-deal-about-fake-news-and-specifically)).

I am wondering if Politics should encourage something similar to SO (research effort and/or clear context with at least one reference for further details)?

**Question:** Should StackOverflow question quality standards also apply for politics questions?

Comment: What makes you think those standards aren't already expected? You should assume they're expected everywhere in the network outside of weird sides like Code Golf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really.

Stack Overflow has a significant benefit in that it can demand all of its questions be *measurably* objective. That's what MCVE is. My experience around the rest of SE is that, most of the time, there's no measurable objectivity standards because it would be impractical. Indeed, Sci-Fi/Fantasy has virtually none (true science and pure opinion are about the only reasons for closure).

Our standard here is considerably less than MCVE. What we need is

1. The question must be related to politics
2. The question must be a serious question, and not one inviting people to make political rants (i.e. [good faith](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3040/a-full-and-objective-description-of-good-faith))

I think we've covered both. There isn't a lot of contention about the rest (with, perhaps, [info-only questions](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/are-give-me-data-only-questions-on-topic) being the one exception)