# Are overly specific questions on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

For example, I have queries regarding a specific US Senate special election in Alabama in the 1930s? Specifically, I hope to get more information on the candidates and their vote shares.

Can I check if such an *overly* specific question is on-topic for this site?

Comment: Assuming they don't fall afoul of any other close reasons, I don't think there's anything wrong with extremely specific questions – though you may never get an answer

Comment: Related question: https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/are-give-me-data-only-questions-on-topic

Comment: Something that old could conceivably of more interest on history SE. Unless it's somehow tied to more recent politics in some way (e.g. cited as precedent for some claim/issue etc.)

Comment: And on [some types](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/61372/who-are-the-two-dead-georgia-voters-who-voted) of specifics the answer might be "no" in practice.